# How to split a table into multiple in Microsoft Acess

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to split one table into multiple in an Access database. For example, I have a single table containing multiple invoices and want to separate it into different tables per invoice. Each invoice is separated by a space of about 8 cells and is in a vertical format, meaning I cannot use the analyzer to just separate the fields into different tables as each field represents a column in all invoices. What can i do in this case?

Comment: Provide a sample of your data and desired output - now the task is not clear... PS. Unrelated tags were removed.

Comment: Don't. This is what queries are for. So, create a query for each of the output you require.